# Laravel group by query

Tags: mysql, laravel, query-builder

I've got this query in Laravel:

```
return $this->hasMany(Facility::class)
            ->select("id", "port_id", "facility",
                DB::raw("(SELECT count('*') FROM port_facilities
                                    WHERE has_it = 1) as has_it_true"),
                DB::raw("(SELECT count('*') FROM port_facilities
                                    WHERE has_it = 0) as has_it_false"))
            ->groupBy('facility');
```

It counts if a port has certain facilities. The problem that I have now is that the `groupBy` is not working. It count's everything instead of `grouping` by facility. Any idea how I could fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use conditional aggregation here:

```
return $this->hasMany(Facility::class)
    ->select("facility",
        DB::raw("COUNT(CASE WHEN has_it = 1 THEN 1 END) AS has_it_true"),
        DB::raw("COUNT(CASE WHEN has_it = 0 THEN 1 END) AS has_it_false"))
    ->groupBy('facility');
```

This would correspond to the following raw MySQL query:

```
SELECT
    facility,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN has_it = 1 THEN 1 END) AS has_it_true,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN has_it = 0 THEN 1 END) AS has_it_false
FROM port_facilities
GROUP BY
    facility;
```

Note that I did not include `id` and `port_id` in the `SELECT` clause, because MySQL might not accept those columns.  In general, when doing `GROUP BY facility`, we may only select `facility` and aggregates of columns other than `facility`.

Answer (score 0):

You're  mixing two Laravel components here. 1 is Relationship definition with Eloquent and the other is using QueryBuilder.

Starting with the query, your 'adapted' query should be something among these lines:

```
Facility::select("id", "port_id", "facility",
                DB::raw("(SELECT count('*') FROM port_facilities
                                    WHERE has_it = 1) as has_it_true"),
                DB::raw("(SELECT count('*') FROM port_facilities
                                    WHERE has_it = 0) as has_it_false"))
            ->groupBy('facility')->get();
```

If you wish to establish a relationship, then in the model you want to specify the relationship you should do something like listed in the docs:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#defining-relationships

Piece of advice: Don't `count('*')` unless you really need to (you can count a single column or a couple and increase some performance), don't mix QueryBuilder with Eloquent unless you really need to and

Comment: This could be made to work, but you'll need to correlate those subqueries to the outer query, e.g. use `(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM port_facilities pf2 WHERE pf1.facility = pf2.facility AND pf2.has_it = 1)`.

Comment: true, I guess I paid more attention to how it was structured than why it wasn't working, your answer is correct :P